# cv qualifiers in decltype of prvalue expression

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

This question came up during my study of `decltype` behavior and its rules in deriving the type of expressions. Is there any reason not to promote common cv-qualifiers if an expression is of prvalue? 
type. Ex:- in the below code the expression `i+j` is just derived by 
`decltype` as `int` rather than `const int`, since `const`ness is common across both variables it could be propagated to the resulting expression as well, although the expression itself is temporary and is not lvalue but when it comes to type derivation it may be useful (as is the case with single value expressions).

**Existing rule : If the value category of expression is prvalue, then `decltype` yields `T`.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 const int i=10;
 const int j=20;  
 cout << is_same<decltype(i), const int>::value << "," << is_same<decltype(j), const int>::value << endl; 
 cout << is_same<decltype(i+j), const int>::value << "," << is_same<decltype(i+j), int>::value << endl;  
 return(0); 
}
```

Comment: you're overlooking the rule that prvalues of built-in type cannot have `const` qualifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the CPP standard draft n4713:

> **8.2.1 Value category [basic.lval]**
>   ...
>   9. ... Class prvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types.

Since `(i + j)` evaluates to a non-class prvalue, it will have a cv-unqualified type and using `decltype` on it yields an `int`.

Comment: perfect this is what i was missing. I was checking at cpp reference and some stack overflow articles. now it is clear!! seems like i have to keep a copy of the standard cpp pdf for reference.

Comment: N4659 is C++17, N4713 is a later draft

Comment: There are drafts available online which you can download. The one for c++17 is this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf

Comment: @M.M:Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I think `decltype(i+j)` will depend on how `operator+` is defined for `i` and `j`, and will not be based on any promotion rules based on `i` and `j` themselves.

Regarding why it is not `const`, I guess it would make it very difficult to apply a move construction/assignement afterwards, and that is considered a important optimization.

Comment: there is no `operator+` for built-in types

Comment: @M.M You cannot redefine them, but are they non-existent? At least cppreference.com talks a lot about "built-in operators", see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: The built-on operators are not called `operator+` and so on

Comment: Yup gpeche makes sense. i mean + operator is there for fundemental types but you can not redefine them albeit they do exist!!